Color range of blank rows gray in two sheets
I need to color blank rows gray, after the top blank row, in two sheets of an Excel workbook.
The sheet names are "Topic 0001" & "Topic 0002".
I get

Compile error: Block if without End if

Sub Test1()
Sheets("Topic 0001").Select
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Range("A1:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
End Sub


I get an error code is useless without knowing what that code is and the error message that came with it. They're both on the screen right in front of you, so there is absolutely no reason you can't put them into your question so that we have that information. You're asking us to give up our time for free to help solve your problem, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by providing the information you have available.

Ken: Received, learning on the fly here thanks for your patience - Compile error: Block if without End if. This I ran a quick search on, but with my beginner knowledge - still learning how to close the statement

The error message tells you how to close it - If block without End If should be clear, and where it needs to go should be as well. You only have one If block in your code, so it should be right after the code that executes as part of that If. That means it would go right after the line with rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 15.


Range("A1:G") has syntax error. The last data row number is missing.



Highligh blank rows (all cells are blank) from Col A to Col G

Microsoft documentation:

Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)


Range.Find method (Excel)

Sub HighLightBlankRow()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rRow As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Topic 0001", "Topic 0002"))
        Set rng = Nothing
        lastRow = Sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Sht.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Sht.Range("A2:G" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            ' get the rows which have at least a blank cell
            Set rng = Application.Intersect(Sht.Range("A:G"), rng.EntireRow)
            For Each rRow In rng.Rows
                If Application.CountA(rRow) = 0 Then ' all blank cells
                    rRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub




Highligh blank cells (may not is in completely blank rows) from Col A to Col G.

Sub HighLightBlankCell()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Topic 0001", "Topic 0002"))
        Set rng = Nothing
        lastRow = Sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Sht.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Sht.Range("A2:G" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End If
    Next
End Sub

